# Google chrome when searching using prefix "is" return This page has been blocked by Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search, google-chrome-extension

i don't know what happened, but i cannot remove this error, i though this was extensions problem so i remove all my extensions but the error still here.

Step 1 - Search using prefix "is"
[image: Step 1 - Search using prefix "is"]

Step 2 - Add space and type any text become like this
[image: Step 2 - Add any search in input text]

Step 3 - Press ENTER and got this error
[image: Step 3 - Press ENTER and got this error]

```
hahpjplbmicfkmoccokbjejahjjpnena is blocked
This page has been blocked by Chrome
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

This problem only happened in my sync account, when i add new profiles without sync to my google account this problem not appear.

Any idea to solve this issue ?

I expect to fix this error

## Update 1

[image: Chrome Extensions]
I don't have any extensions right now, but the problem persist

Comment: It means you still have an extension named "Improved Search" that intercepts the `is` keyword. Remove the extension through the puzzle piece icon menu in the browser toolbar and be careful not to install unwanted extensions.

Comment: @wOxxOm i'm uninstall all extensions but the problem still persist

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: this question is probably not a good fit for stackoverflow but for what it's worth, try checking chrome settings: chrome://settings/searchEngines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your sync data, this method should be working but you will lose all your sync data like bookmark, history, etc. So please be aware before you doing this. And you can do backup or anything to prevent data loss

### STEP 1 : Remove all your sync data

1. Got to chrome settings
2. In the "Accounts" section, select Sync and Google services.
3. Select Review your synced data.
4. At the bottom, select Reset sync.

### STEP 2 : Create new profile and resync your account to your new profile

Because in STEP 1 is not remove anything in your current chrome profile, so you need to create new profile and sign in to your google account

### STEP 3 : Make sure the problem is gone, and you can remove your old profile